# Can 'NEWS' in a Debian package be made by the packager/maintainer?

Tags: debian, package-management, debian-policy

I have seen some packages having a separate NEWS file while there are many which don't. AFAIU it, having a NEWS.Debian.gz notes some very important/rare information as well as have possibly news about backward-compatibility going forward. This seems to be something in the DD's or DM's hand as there doesn't seem to be any info. in [debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/). Is there something that a prospective packager should look at ?

Comment: The `NEWS` file that you are talking about is made by the Debian package maintainers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NEWS files are documented in the [Debian Developer's Reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/ch06.en.html#bpp-news-debian). There is more background information in the [mailing list thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2002/07/msg00267.html) which led to their creation.